# How to create ordered list of results in views using drupal 6?

Tags: drupal, view

Hi I would like to know how to create an oredered list of results in my block views in Drupal 6.

I think this is something basic, but I am unable to resolve this problem.

Ok, I have 5 results(article titles; for simplicity I will be using just field Title) something like this:

```
NATO is killing people in Libya
Who are the "rebels"?
NATO War Against Libya's Khaddafi is meeting resistance
People of Libya will not surrender
Libya's rebel army chief killed - video
```

And I want it to look like this:

```
1. NATO is killing people in Libya
2. Who are the "rebels"?
3. NATO War Against Libya's Khaddafi is meeting resistance
4. People of Libya will not surrender
5. Libya's rebel army chief killed - video
```

How to achieve this orederd list?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Under Basic Settings in your view change the style to HTML List, and also change it to ordered list in there.

[image: choose ordered list]

Answer (score 1):

Although 'HTML List/Ordered list' does fine for a results set where the number of hits/results is less than the pager size (Items per page), it fails when the results are more than the pager size.  That's because all this does is to replace the `ul` tag with a `ol` tag.  The result is that when the second page is viewed the list numbering again begins at one. (E.g., if setup for 10 items per page, page two shows results 11-20, and the numbering again displays as 1. through 10.)

To correctly number the results, add the field "Global: View results counter" and set the label to blank.

PS, if you want periods after the numbers, then rewrite the output as `[counter].`